Using data-row-callback for jquery datatables
I'm trying to reuse my tables as much as possible, so when I try to use data-row-callback with an existing function, I get a val.apply is not a function error
Here is my table tag
<table id="dataTable" class="content-wrapper table table-striped" data-ajax-url="?handler=Data" data-order='[[1, "desc"]]' data-server-side="true" data-row-callback="function(row, data, index) { myCallback(row, data, index); }">

Here is the error generated upon page load
Uncaught TypeError: val.apply is not a function
    at dataTables.js:6289:16
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _fnCallbackFire (dataTables.js:6288:50)
    at _fnDraw (dataTables.js:3401:5)
    at _fnAjaxUpdateDraw (dataTables.js:4216:3)
    at dataTables.js:4105:5
    at Object.callback [as success] (dataTables.js:4008:4)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2:28294)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:29039)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2:79800)

Here is my callback function
function myCallback(row, data, index) {
     console.log("called");
     $('td:eq(2)', row).html((data.reportType == true) ? "Self" : "Other");
}

If I use this snippet it works fine
var dataTable = $(id).DataTable({
     ...,
     rowCallback: myCallback,
     ...}

